# Deleting a field using plugin in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, fields-attributes, delete

I am trying to write a function to delete a field using plugin in QGIS 3.24.
I have build a plugin , which consists of QgsFieldComboBox. So I can select a field from the combo box to delete (from  the layer selected), take it as input and delete it.
Here is the plugin -

[image]

Here is the code -

def delete_field(self):
layer = self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer()

#HERE WE ARE TAKING THE INPUT OF FIELD SELECTED IN COMBOBOX
#delField_cb is the object of the QgsFieldComboBox

```
    delF = self.dlg.delField_cb.currentField()
    print(delF)
   
    
    
    
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteAttributes:
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([delF])
        layer.updateFields()
```

def delete_field_Cb(self,vlayer):
self.dlg.delField_cb.setLayer(vlayer)
field = self.dlg.delField_cb.setLayer(vlayer)

def run(self):

```
   self.dlg.cb_layer.layerChanged.connect(self.delete_field_Cb)
   self.dlg.delete_field_btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_field_Cb)
```

I am stuck and gettting the error as:

field = self.dlg.delField_cb.setLayer(vlayer)
TypeError: QgsFieldComboBox.setLayer(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'bool'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.dlg.delete_field_btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_field_Cb)` this causes your error because when the `clicked` event send a boolean to the called function

What you want is most likely `self.dlg.delete_field_btn.clicked.connect(self.delete_field)`

Also in your `delField_cb` function:
`field = self.dlg.delField_cb.setLayer(vlayer)` doesn't seem to do anything

EDIT: for the second exception replace
`res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([delF])`
with

```py
index_field = layer.fields().indexFromName(delF)
res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([index_field])
```

Comment: Now i am getting this as an error                                                                                 SystemError: returned a result with an error set 
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/MTTUSER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\abtdmodel\ABTDModel.py", line 288, in delete_field
    res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([delF])
SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: yES GOT IT , THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to my Error.
I had to put in the index of the field which i want to delete and not the field name in

```
res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([*delF]*)
```

so to get the index we write the code as:

```
def delete_field(self):
        layer = self.dlg.cb_layer.currentLayer()
        delF = self.dlg.delField_cb.currentField()
      # THIS TAKES THE INDEX OF THE SELECTED FIELD FROM COMBO BOX
        idx = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(delF)

        caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
        if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteAttributes:
            res = layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([idx])
            layer.updateFields()
```